# How can I boost mouse cursor speed in game menu?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

My mouse cursor is extremely slow in game menus, but working normally in game and on my laptop in general.

My monitor's refresh rate is 59 Hz. [As this post counsels](https://old.reddit.com/r/trucksim/comments/448p6p/atsslow_mouse_cursor_in_menus/czt399z/), I chose the game's setting of 60 Hz. The only  other setting is 'default rate', but this doesn't stipulate the number of Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adjusting it by editing your profile's "controls.sii" file.

Look for a setting of "c_msens". For example:

```
config_lines[22]: "constant c_msens 0.330000"
```

Keep in mind, this constant also affects the Camera and Steering, if you are using the mouse to steer.

Alternatively, you could get a mouse with a DPI setting mapped to the mouse itself. This way you can change the sensitivity with a mouse button click.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Do I decrease or increase that 0.33? (2) What units is this 0.33? How much difference does 1 make?

Comment: Mind responding in (by editing) your prior comment pls? Comment chains are more grueling to read.

Comment: @Joyce, you want to increase the value of sensitivity. I do not know what units mouse sensitivity is measured.